# C# one-liner to grab specific data from an RSS feed

Tags: c#, linq, rss

I'm looking for a C# "one-liner" (need not strictly be a single line, but very short is preferable) way to download an RSS feed from a given HTTP URL, and extract specific data. Robustness be damned. Something that doesn't require any external libraries.

Specifically I want to count the number of `<item>`s in the RSS. But some kind of LINQ method that could be reused to, say for example, return a list of the item `<title>` elements would be most useful, if it can be kept short.

Comment: Strongly disagree with closure. This is clearly a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create("http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/rss.aspx")).Items.Count();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Regex.Matches(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/7180063"), "<entry>").Count
```

Comment: +1 for staying true to "one-liner"

Comment: @Nate Your answer lends itself to a cleaner one-liner too

Answer (score 5):

What about something like this:

```
var rssFeed = XDocument.Load("http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/rss.aspx");

var posts = from item in rssFeed.Descendants("item")
            select new
            {
                Title     = (string)item.Element("title"),
                Published = (DateTime?)item.Element("pubDate"),
                Url       = (string)item.Element("link"),
            };
```

[Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx).